# How to separate words in a string with commas properly?

Tags: ruby

I have a helper method:

```
def get_str(exam)
  @value = ""
  if exam.is_mc
    @value << "MC, "
  end
  if exam.is_ms
    @value << "MS, "
  end
  if exam.is_ng
    @value << "NG"
  end
  return @value
end
```

When all the three conditions are satisfied I get a string: `MC, MS, NG`

But if only first condition is satisfied I get the string: `MC,`

I don't want to show the comma in that case.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to pass the concatenation duties to [`Array#join`](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-join).

```
def get_str(exam)
  @value = []
  @value << "MC" if exam.is_mc
  @value << "MS" if exam.is_ms
  @value << "NG" if exam.is_ng
  @value = @value.join ', '
end
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The return value is correct, but `@value` is different from the OP's code.

Comment: @sawa my answer was not really different from this one, so I deleted mine to prevent duplicates

Answer (score 0):

This will work too:

```
def get_str(exam)
  ['MC', 'MS', 'NG'].select{|i| exam.send("is_#{i.downcase}").join(', ')
end
```

Only real advantage is that it will be easier to add more strings patterns.